# Monotone functions and non-vanishing of derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The following result is well known:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on $(a, b)$ and $f'$ is non-zero on $(a, b)$ then $f$ is strictly monotone on $[a, b]$.

However if the derivative vanishes at a finite number of points in $(a, b)$ and apart from these derivative maintains a constant sign in $(a, b)$ then also the function is strictly monotone on $[a, b]$ (just split the interval into finite number of intervals using these points where derivative vanishes and $f$ is strictly monotone in same direction in each of these intervals).

> Let's suppose now that $f$ is strictly monotone and continuous in $[a, b]$ and differentiable in $(a, b)$. What can we say about set of points $$A = \{x \mid x \in (a, b), f'(x) = 0\}$$ Can it be infinite? Can it be uncountable? How large the set $A$ can be?

Comment: See my answer to [Set of zeroes of the derivative of a pathological function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151931/set-of-zeroes-of-the-derivative-of-a-pathological-function) -- specifically, item (1) in the 2nd paragraph of my answer, which says that this question (along with other similar questions) is answered in [*Level sets of derivatives*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-272-01/S0002-9947-1982-0656484-0/) by David Preiss (see Theorem 5.4(2) on p. 180). I think this characterization allows $A$ to have cardinality continuum, but I don't have time right now to dig into this.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your answer which contains very good references. I will take some time out to study those as well as the paper of David Preiss.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's clear that $A$ must have empty interior. At least for *closed* sets that's a characterization:

**Theorem** If $A\subset[0,1]$ is compact with empty interior then there exists a strictly increasing $f\in C^1([0,1])$ such that $A$ is the zero set of $f'$.

**Exercise** Modify the following proof to show that we can even get $f$ *infinitely differentiable*.

Proof. Say the connected components of $[0,1]\setminus A$ are $I_1,\dots$. Each $I_n$ is a relatively open interval; there exist $a_n$, $b_n$ with $$I_n\cap(0,1)=(a_n,b_n).$$

Choose $f_n\in C^1(\Bbb R)$ so that $f_n(t)=0$ for all $t\le a_n$, $f(t)=1$ for all $t\ge b_n$, and $f_n'(t)>0$ for all $t\in(a_n,b_n)$. Choose $c_n>0$ so that $$\sum_n c_n\sup_t(|f_n(t)|+|f_n'(t)|)<\infty,$$and let $$f=\sum_n c_nf_n.$$The hypothesis implies that $$f'=\sum_nc_nf_n',$$so $f$ is continuously differentiable and $$\{t\in[0,1]:f'(t)=0\}=A.$$And $f$ is strictly increasing: Say $0\le x<y\le 1$. Since $A$ has empty interior there exists $t\in(x,y)$ with $f'(t)>0$. QED

Comment: Very nice theorem and the proof. Since cantor set also has empty interior, it means we can have $A$ uncountable. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh And $A$ could be a "fat Cantor set", so that $A$ can have positive measure.

Comment: I was also looking for $A$ with positive measure and found this nice article https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/08/the_difference_between_measure.html which gives the same fat cantor set as example.

Answer (score 12):

On $[0,1]$, consider
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac x{1-x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}=\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)}{\left(1-x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right)^2}
$$

Comment: beats me completely. so at least a countable infinity of points can be in $A$.+1

Comment: BTW do we know if we can have $A$ uncountable?

Comment: $A$ can be any compact set with empty interior. Answr to appear when I've typed it...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: eagerly waiting for the answer.

Comment: Well there it is. (Thought it was going to take longer or I wouldn't bothered announcing it in advance...)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x) = \int_x^1 (\sin(\frac{1}{t})+1) dt$, with $f(0)$ defined so that $f$ is continuous at $0$. This function is $C^1$ on $(0, 1)$, strictly decreasing and continuous on $[0, 1]$, and has zero derivative for every zero of $\sin(\frac{1}{t})+1$, of which there are infinitely many.

Further, consider an arbitrary strictly monotone $C^1$ function $g$ on $[0, 1]$. Sard's theorem tells us that the set of critical values of $g$ has measure zero. <s>And if I'm not mistaken, if we have Lipschitz continuity for $g^{-1}$, we can conclude that the set of critical points must also have measure zero.</s>

I don't know about having uncountably many critical points, though.

Comment: No, Lipschitz does not imply measure zero.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Does it work if $g$'s inverse is Lipschitz? According to this thread (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139883/why-does-a-lipschitz-function-f-mathbbrd-to-mathbbrd-map-measure-zero-s) Lipschitz functions map measure zero sets to measure zero sets, and since $g$ is strictly monotonic, it's invertible.

Comment: If $g$ is increasing and the inverse of $g$ is Lipschitz then $|g(s)-g(t)|\ge c|s-t|$ for some $c>0$, hence $g'\ge c$ _everywhere_ and $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Great observation, thank you.