# Is function $f(x)$ is one to one if $f'(x) \ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Is function $f(x)$ is one to one if $f'(x)  \ge 0$.

Can we say a function $f(x)$ is one-one if $f(x)$ is Continous and $f'(x) \ge 0$. For example $f(x)=x^3$ is one-one since $$f'(x)=3x^2 \ge 0$$ But why most of the books give $f(x)$ is one-one if $f'(x) \gt 0$. Can

Comment: $f(x)=3$ is not 1 to 1

Comment: You have a reasoning fallacy here. The statement "every function differentiable with positive derivative is one-to-one" is true, and can be proven. But what you say is "every function differentiable with non-negative derivative is one-to-one" (which is false), and your argument is "this must be true, *because here is an example.*" You cannot prove a universal statement ("every function satisfying A is B") by giving an example ("there exists a functions with A that is B").

Answer (score 1):

Boring example: a constant function has $f'(x)=0$ everywhere, and is clearly not one-to-one.

Comment: ok fine but for some functions like $x^3$ and $x^5$ $f'(x) \ge 0$ but still they are one-one right? So does it mean derivative should be zero at exactly one point?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Not quite. Consider $f$ defined by $f(x)=x+\sin(x)^2$.

Comment: @Umeshshankar See [Monotone functions and non-vanishing of derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845927/monotone-functions-and-non-vanishing-of-derivative) for a complete characterization. Note that strict monotonicity is equivalent to injectivity for continuous real functions.

Answer (score 1):

No. $f'(x) \ge 0$ does not ensure one-one as shown by the examples in other answers and comments. However, $f'(x) > 0$ does.
By the Mean Value Theorem, for $h > 0$,  $ \ f(x+h) - f(x) = hf'(\eta) > 0$ for some $\eta \in (x,x+h)$. So $f$ is strictly increasing. Therefore $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x =y$ since otherwise either $x <y$ in which case $f(x) < f(y)$ or $x >y$, in which case $f(x) > f(y)$.

Similarly, $f' < 0$ also makes $f$ one-one.

Comment: Ok that i understood clearly. But when $f'(x) \gt 0$ decides injectivity of a function, some functions also have derivative zero at some points.what i learned from all the comments above is, a function $f(x)$ is One-one if $f'(x) \gt 0$ but $f'(x)$ can be zero at finite number of points or countably infinite number of points. Does this make any sense?