# Find the condition for $f^{-1}$ to exist.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

> If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)= x^3+ px^2 + qx+ k \sin{x}$, where $k,p,q \in \mathbb R$.
>
> Find the condition for $f^{-1}$ to exist.

Can somebody please give me a **Hint** how to solve this problem.

**EDIT(After getting hints):**
If we can show that $f$ is strictly increasing, then we can get that $f$ is injective. So we want $f^{'}(x)>0$ and that gives me $p^2 < 3(q + k \cos{x}).$

As $f^{'}(x)$ will be a quadratic polynomial and we want it to be strictly positive or strictly negative but as coefficient of $x^2$ is positive, we can only get derivative to be strictly positive if discriminant is $<0.$

Comment: $f$ needs to be a bijection.

Comment: @ervx, that much I know. How to find conditions for that is a question.

Comment: @MercyKing That's not really a hint, is it?

Comment: @MercyKing. It's okay if $f'(x) = 0$ at discrete points. For example, consider $x^3$. But $f$ must be strictly monotone.

Comment: The condition is $f'(x)\ge 0$ or $f'(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, or equivalently $p^2-3q\le 0$.

Comment: @MercyKing, don't we want the derivative to be strictly positive?

Comment: @User `derivative to be strictly positive?` No, it's enough for the derivative to be $\ge 0$ with only isolated zeros. Take for example $y = x^3$ which is *strictly* increasing, yet its derivative is $y'=0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @dxiv, but if we are taking derivative to be $\ge 0$, how can we eliminate the case of constant function or somethibg like that?

Comment: @User Emphasis on "*only isolated zeros*". Actually, it's enough that the *interior* of the zero set of the derivative be empty, see for example [Monotone functions and non-vanishing of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845927/monotone-functions-and-non-vanishing-of-derivative).

Comment: We want $\forall x, 3x^2+2px + q - k \cos x \geq 0$, since $3x^2+2px+q-k \cos x \geq 3x^2 + 3px +q -|k| $, a sufficient condition is $p^2 \leq  3(q-|k|)$. can't figure out necessary condition though.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh, How did you get $3px$ in the second equation? Is that a typo?

Comment: Yikes, it is indeed a typo. should be $2px$.

Comment: @dxiv, I agree with your argument. So, you mean, to check whether a given function is strictly increasing or decreasing we need to check that $f^{'}(x)\ge 0$ or $f^{'}(x)\le 0$ and then we need to verify that $f^{'}(x)= 0$ is on isolated points only. Am I right?

Comment: @User That is sufficient, indeed. The weaker condition derived in the linked post is enough, though, which is that the set of zeros of the derivative $\,\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f'(x) = 0 \}\,$ has an empty interior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

Check $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$.

Check $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x)$.

Note that $f$ is continuous.

Find conditions to make it strictly increasing.

Comment: Limits will depends on sign of $p$ and $q$. So how can we find them?

Comment: The limit should be independent of $p$, $q$ and $k$, as $x$ is very huge in magnitude. $x^3$ is the dominant term.

Comment: Okie, so $f$ is continuous and it takes values between $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, so $f$ is surjective. So we just need to find the conditions for which $f$ is injective. Right?

Comment: yup, you are done with surjective.

Comment: For injectivity, can you please check my edit in the question?

Comment: After we differentiate it we can a quadratic function plus a trigonometry function rather than a quadratic right. I wonder must $k$ be zero. Need to think carefully.

Comment: Yeah, got my mistake. Any hint to proceed at this step?

Comment: not yet, still thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly increasig functions are injective, and hence, have inverse.

Comment: Two-sided inverses?