# Strictly increasing function implies positive derivative?

Tags: calculus

We know that a if function $f:[a,b]→R$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and   $f′>0$ on $(a,b)$, except at a finite number of points  in $(a,b)$, $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$. Is there any counterexample that shows the converse fails?

Comment: It's given that f is continuous. I want to know, if the function is increasing strictly, does this mean that the derivative of the function is positive everywhere except, possibly at a finite number of points in (a,b)?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1845973) to a very related question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: On $[0,1],$ consider the function

$$f(x) = \int_0^x t\sin^2 (1/t)\, dt.$$