# "Constant" points of an increasing function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, real-numbers

I just learned that the discontinuity points of an increasing function are countable. Then what about the "constant" points?

Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow R$ be an increasing function on a bounded interval, i.e., $f(x)\leq f(y)$ if $a<x<y<b$. Further assume that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Let $C=\{x\in (a,b)| \ f'(x)=0\}$. Then, is it true that $f(C)$ is countable, or at least $m(f(C))=0$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on the real line?

I suspect it is true since the "inverse" of $f$ is also increasing so that its discontinuity point is countable. How should I show it with rigor? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The way you've defined allows constant functions.

Comment: @Ovi Any problem arises when $f$ is constant?

Comment: Well for constant functions the derivative is $0$ everywhere so $C = (a, b)$, which is uncountable.

Comment: @Ovi yes but $f(C)$ is a singleton so it is countable.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake I read the question wrong.

Comment: See [Monotone functions and non-vanishing of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845927/monotone-functions-and-non-vanishing-of-derivative).

Comment: OK. I solved it.
By Sard's theorem, $m(f(C))=0$ if we further assume that $f$ is $C^1$.