# Is $f$ increasing

Tags: real-analysis

The Cantor-Lebesgue function gives an example of a function which is increasing but whose derivative (where it exists) is $0$. But is the following true?

> Let $f$ is a continuous function on a compact set, $K \subset \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f'$ exists and $f'>0$ on a dense subset of $K$, then $f$ is increasing.

Does it make a difference if $K$ is an interval or not?

Comment: See [Monotone functions and non-vanishing of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845927/monotone-functions-and-non-vanishing-of-derivative).

Comment: I suppose K is a subset of $\mathbb R$. To define derivative f at a point it has to be defined in a neighborhood of the point. Some clarification on what kind of K you want to consider is needed. Perhaps you want to take K to be a compact interval.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The spaces I had in mind were indeed in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. I shall make the edit.

Comment: You are still of the mark!. A set like $\{0,1/2,1/3,...\}$ is compact in $\mathbb R$. How do you define derivative of a function defined on this set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Minkowski's question mark function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function) is a strictly increasing continuous function $?$ on $[0,1]$, with $?(0)=0$ and $?(1)=1$, whose derivative exists and is $0$ on the rationals.  Thus $f(x) = x - ?(x)$ is a continuous function whose derivative is $+1$ on a dense subset of $[0,1]$, but $f(1) = f(0)=0$ so $f$ is not increasing.