# Non negative derivative, not being zero function on all subintervals, implies strictly increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem

> Suppose $ f$ is a continuous function on interval $I$ and that the derivative $ f'$ of $f$ exists and is nonnegative everywhere on the interior of $I$. Also  suppose that there is no sub-interval of $I$ such that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$ in the subinterval. Prove that $f$ is a strictly increasing function.

*Attempt.* I stepped on this when proving that $x-\sin x$ is strictly increasing. One could use the above result, or easier, the MVT on a positive $x>0$ and the nearest $n\pi+\pi/2$ from the left. However i could not transfer this idea to the general case, as stated above, in order to provide a proof of this general result.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Assume that there are $x<y$ in $I$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Let $z$ be the point where the maximum of $|f(r)-f(x)|$ is attained for $r\in [x,y]$. If $f(r)>f(x)$. Then by Lagrange's mean value theorem, there is a point in $(r,y)$ with negative derivative. If $f(r)<f(x)$, then there is a point in $(x,r)$ with negative derivative. Therefore, $f(r)=f(x)$, which implies that $f$ is constant on $(x,y)$. This contradicts that $f'$ cannot be zero on the interval $(x,y)$.

Comment: I see, very nice. Just a typo: i guess  you mean "if $f(z)>f(x)$ " etc

Comment: There are two parts. In one the assumption is $f(r)>f(x)$ in the other the assumption is $f(r)<f(x)$.

Comment: Of course there are two parts. Point $z$ is where max is attained. Don't you take the cases: $f(z)>f(x), f(z)<f(x)$, which lead to contradiction, and so $f(z)=f(x)$, giving $f$ constant on $ [x,y]$?

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1845927/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f'(x) \ge 0$ implies that $f$ is (weakly) increasing:
$$
 a < b \implies f(a) \le f(b) \, ,
$$
this follows from the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

It remains to exclude that $f(a) = f(b)$ for some $a < b$: Then
$$
 a \le x \le b \implies f(a) \le f(x) \le f(b) = f(a) \, ,
$$
i.e. $f$ is *constant* on $[a, b]$, and therefore $f'(x) = 0$ on $[a, b]$, contradicting the assumption that there is no subinterval on which the derivative is zero.