# Strict concavity and convexity when there is an inflection

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

$f(x)=xe^x$ is such that $f'(x)=e^x+xe^x$ and so $f''(x)=(2+x)e^x$. I know that $f''(x)>0\iff x>-2$ and $f''(x)<0\iff x<-2$, while $x=-2$ is an inflection point.
Can I say that in $(-\infty,2)$ the function is STRICTLY concave and in $(2,\infty)$ is STRICTLY convex? Can I include also $x=2$ in both of these intervals?

Comment: 2 in the intervals is wrong, should be -2.

Comment: Assume $f'' \ge 0$, and let $A$ be the [zero set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function#Zero_set) of $f''$, then $f$ is *strictly* convex if $A$ has empty interior. This follows directly from the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1845973/291201) to [Monotone functions and non-vanishing of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845927/monotone-functions-and-non-vanishing-of-derivative).

Comment: @dxiv so if I prove that in a right neighbourhood of $x=-2$ I have $f'(x)\neq 0$ then can I conclude that $f$ is strict convex?

Comment: @Nik This has nothing to do with the zeros of $f'$. But you know that the zero set of $f''$ only contains one isolated point $A = \{-2\}$. That means $A$ has empty interior, which in turn implies that $f'$ is *strictly* increasing, so $f$ is *strictly* convex.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in my previous comment! I would like to say $f''(x)\neq 0$ in a neighbourhood of $x=-2$...now my idea works? @dxiv

Comment: @Nik Yes, as long as you know (or prove) the result from the linked post.

Answer (score 3):

By [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function)

> A differentiable function f is (strictly) concave on an interval if and only if its derivative function f ′ is (strictly) monotonically decreasing on that interval, that is, a concave function has a non-increasing (decreasing) slope.

And for your example $f'$ is strictly increasing (resp. decreasing) on $[-2, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, -2]$ (despite having $f'' = 0$ at $x = -2$) so we can include $x = -2$

---

To elaborate, this comes about as for a general real valued differentiable function we have:
$f' > 0 \implies f$ strictly increasing, but the converse is not always true

For example if $f(x) = x^3$ then $f$ is strictly increasing but $f'(0) = 0$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know what the bot is talking about. The answer is perfectly clear as written. Welcome to the community.

Comment: 2 is not the correct value (see my comment bellow the question).

Comment: Apologies I didn't read it carefully enough - I've edited the reply

Comment: So in $[-2,\infty)$ is strict concave and in $(-\infty,2]$ is strict convex?

Comment: Other way round, $f$ is concave on $(-\infty, -2]$ and convex on $[-2, \infty)$