Strictly Increasing Function With Periodic First Derivative
I was tasked with the following question:
Construct the functions F such that

F has domain R
F is differentiable
F is strictly increasing.
F′ is periodic with period 2π, and F′ is not constant.

This is what I've been able to come up with so far:
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume $a \neq 0$. Let $F(x)$ be a function such that $F(x)=a\sin x + Cx$ s.t. $C > |a|$.

Showing that $F$ has domain $\mathbb{R}$:
It can be shown that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \sin x$ and $C x$ exist, hence $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, F(x)$ exists, which means $F$ has domain $\mathbb{R}$.

WTS $F$ is diffable.
We find that $$F'(x)=a \cos x + C.$$
It can be seen that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, a \cos x$ exists and $C$ exists. Hence $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, F'(x)$ exists, which means $F$ is diffable.

Showing that $F$ is strictly increasing.
1st. Assume $a>0$. We know $C>|a|\ge a$. Since $-1 \le \cos x$, $a \cos x + C \ge -a + C > -a + a = 0$, which means $F'(x)>0$.
2nd. Assume $a<0$. We know $C>|a|\ge -a$. Since $\cos x \le 1$, $a \cos x + C > a + C > a - a = 0$, which means $F'(x)>0$.
Hence $\forall a \neq 0, F'(x)>0 \ $for all x$ 
 \in \mathbb{R} $. By MVT, this means $F$ is strictly increasing.

Prove that $F'$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ and $F'$ is not
constant.
Let's look at $$F'(x)=a \cos x + C.$$
It can be shown that $F'(0)=a+C$ while $F'(\pi/2)=C$. Since $a \neq 0$, $F'(0) \neq F'(\pi/2)$, thus $F'$ is not constant. Note that $\cos x$
is periodic with period $2\pi$. Since $a \neq 0$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}$, thus by trigonometric properties, $F'(x)=a \cos x + C$ is
also periodic.


My confusion:
It's not necessary that $C > |a|$ (or $F'(x)>0$) ,because $C=|a|$ can work too: Think about $F(x)=\sin x + x$. It's still strictly increasing even though  $C =|a|$ Thus there are points where $F'(x)=0$. However, I would not be able to prove it using the corollary that positive derivative implies strictly increasing and have to prove from the definition of increasing. I couldn't achieve this.

Oops, it should be $F'$. My bad

Regarding points where $F'(x) =0$ note that those points partition the real line into a set of disjoint open intervals. If the derivative is positive on an open interval the function itself is strictly increasing on corresponding closed interval (provided it is continuous there). So those points where derivative vanishes are not a problem. See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1845927/72031

So, for the sinx+x case, I would need to prove that the function is increasing on each adjacent periodic interval and then connect them using continuity?

If $F(x) =\sin x+x$ then $F'(x) =0$ for $x=(2n+1)\pi,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and everywhere else (like on intervals $(-\pi, \pi), (\pi, 3\pi)$) the derivative is positive.Then $F(x) $ is strictly increasing on each of the intervals $\dots, [-3\pi,-\pi],[-\pi,\pi],[\pi,3\pi],\dots$ and hence on $\mathbb{R} $. Continuity is needed to ensure the behavior of $F$ on a closed interval (like $[-\pi, \pi] $) by using the sign of $F'$ on the corresponding open interval (like $(-\pi, \pi) $).

You should to able to convince (and prove) yourself that the following is true: if $a<b<c$ and $f$ is strictly increasing on each of the intervals $[a, b] $ and $[b, c] $ then $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a, c] $. The result does not hold for open intervals.

You seem to be trying to find all functions of a certain class that have the necessary properties. Why not just find one, as required. You're on the right track. Now ask yourself, "Would choosing $a = 1$ be viable? Because it'd sure make the algebra nicer!" Then you see that you need $C \ge |a|$, but the "=" case is a little touchy...so why not choose a value of $C$ that's solidly greater than $a$, and easy to work with arithmetically/algebraically.
Once you've chosen a specific function, you just have to show it's differentiable and periodic and increasing. ("Defined on the reals" really doesn't need proof -- sine and $x \to Cx$ are both defined on the reals, and you can just add them: the sum of two functions on $\mathbb R$ is again a function on $\mathbb R$.)
I hope this helps you focus your work.

BTW, all the work you did is exactly the scratch-work I'd do for this problem before realizing "Hey, I could get specific here and simplify!"

I think I get it for Question 1:
since F' is positive everywhere else (like on intervals (−π,π),(π,3π)
) , and since F is continuous on each of the intervals …,[−3π,−π],[−π,π],[π,3π],…, By the MVT  F(x) is strictly increasing on each of the intervals …,[−3π,−π],[−π,π],[π,3π],…
and hence on R.
