# Is the derivative of a monotonically increasing function positve?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I know that if the derivative of a function is positive on $\left(a,b\right)$  then that function  is increasing on $\left(a,b\right)$ . However not sure if the opposite always holds. Here is my approach:

Let $f\left(x\right)$ monotone increasing on $\left(a,b\right)$ Then for every $a_1$ and $b_1$ of $\left(a,b\right)$  such that if $a_1<b_1$, it holds that $f\left(a_1\right)<f\left(b_1\right)$,

So we have
$$ \frac{f\left(b_1\:\right)-f\left(a_1\right)}{b_1-a_1}>0\:$$

From Langranges' theorem we have that there exists a $c$ in $\left(a_1,b_1\right)$ such that

$$ f'\left(c\right)\:=\:\frac{f\left(b_1\:\right)-f\left(a_1\right)}{b_1-a_1}>0\: $$
This means that for every subsegment of $\left(a,b\right)$, we can find a $c$, such that it's derivative at $c$ is positive. Meaning that the derivative of $f(x)$ on $\left(a,b\right)$  is always positive for every point in $\left(a,b\right)$.

Comment: You don't get to choose $c$, so you don't know that every value in $(a,b)$ is covered by this argument.

Comment: Looks fine assuming the function is differentiable everywhere on $(a,b)$.

Comment: You want to start with some point $x\in(a,b)$ and show that $f'(x)>0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f$ strictly increasing does not imply $f' \gt 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169243/f-strictly-increasing-does-not-imply-f0)

Comment: $f(x) = x^3$ is monotonically increasing, but the derivative is not positive at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Does my proof however guarantee that there will be at least one point at which the derivative will be positive?

Comment: Imagine "$x^3$" cut and glued over and under cut "$x^3$" . So can be done infinite times - sorry if idea is badly explained - can you imagine it?

Comment: @AlexParker Yes, and you can in fact guarantee infinitely many points where $f'$ is strictly positive, since you can recursively apply MVT to $\,(a,c), (c,b)\,$.

Answer (score 2):

A function strictly increasing need not have a (strictly) positive derivative at all points. For instance $f(x)=x^3$ is monotonically (strictly) increasing on the interval $(-1,1)$, but the derivative is not always positive on that interval: Namely: $f'(0)=0$.